# How to configure BCryptPasswordEncoder in security xml

Tags: java, spring-security

I read every API and documentation of spring security but i cant find how to configure the BCryptPasswordEncoder strength parameter in the spring security bean xml.

trying to do somthing like: `BCryptPasswordEncoder(int strength);`

My security.xml:

```
<bean id="bCryptPasswordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <security:password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you would use [Spring's constructor dependency injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-constructor-injection) on the BCryptPasswordEncoder.

```
<bean id="bCryptPasswordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="100"/>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <security:password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

As of Spring 3.1 you can make this more concise [using the c-namespace](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-c-namespace). For example:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="bCryptPasswordEncoder"
          class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"
          c:strength="100"/>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <security:password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

You will notice that in this example

- There is a new xmlns:c declaration
- the value after c: in bCryptPasswordEncoder corresponds to the constructor argument name. Alternatively you could use c:_0 to specify the index.

See the previous link for more details on the c-namespace.